# How do you get an audiobook to repeat?

Tags: iphone, itunes

When I made a playlist from a book from audible it shows up on my iPhone as a playlist but it won't play and in fact says "won't play."  In the past I have done this successfully and I don't know what the problem is. I was so disappointed not to have the ability to repeat An audiobook. I like to have an audiobook repeat if I go to sleep listening to it. In the past I have had a book jump from Austen to Auschwitz and it was very unnerving. I wish they would address this issue and not anticipate how someone is going to use a certain application. I still listen to books on my old classic iPod and you could make playlists from books right on the device it was so easy!   Does anyone know how to address this?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). As for your question, I've closed this because as it appears to be a duplicate of another question. Hopefully that helps you get to a solution.